# issue with xaml alignment xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin form cross app. I am using Navigation drawer where I need to show items/subitems . Single are showing properly but issue is with items and subitem.. in that case.. text is showing vertically.

This is screen shot of current code
[image]

Now you can see that text are appearing vertically and same for sub menu items..
I actually want to show like below

[image]

My xaml is as below

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Menu" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource WhiteColor}">
        <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

            <!-- 
         This StackLayout you can use for other
         data that you want to have in your menu drawer
    -->
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource BlueColor}"
                         HeightRequest="75">

                <Label Text="Menu"
                       FontSize="20"
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       TextColor="White"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout>

                    <!--DashBoard-->

                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                             Orientation="Horizontal"
                             Padding="20,10,0,0"
                             Spacing="20">

                    <Image Source="dashbaordmenuicon.png"
                           WidthRequest="30"
                           HeightRequest="30"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" />

                    <Label Text="Dashboards"
                           FontSize="18"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           FontFamily="ProximaNova"
                           TextColor="#637188"/>


                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                 Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 Padding="30,5,0,10"
                                 Spacing="20">

                        <Image Source="summarymenuicon.png"
                               WidthRequest="30"
                               HeightRequest="30"
                               VerticalOptions="Center" />

                        <Label Text="Summary"
                               FontSize="15"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               FontFamily="ProximaNova"
                               TextColor="#98a4b4"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                 Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 Padding="30,5,0,10"
                                 Spacing="20">

                        <Image Source="spendinghistoryicon.png"
                               WidthRequest="30"
                               HeightRequest="30"
                               VerticalOptions="Center" />

                        <Label Text="pending History"
                               FontSize="18"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               FontFamily="ProximaNova"
                               TextColor="#98a4b4"/>
                    </StackLayout>


                </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
                <!--Dreams-->

                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             Orientation="Horizontal"
                             Padding="20,10,0,0"
                             Spacing="20">

                    <Image Source="dreamsicon.png"
                           WidthRequest="30"
                           HeightRequest="30"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" />

                    <Label Text="Dreams"
                           FontSize="18"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           FontFamily="ProximaNova"
                           TextColor="#637188"/>


                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 Padding="30,5,0,10"
                                 Spacing="20">

                        <Image Source="adddreamicon.png"
                               WidthRequest="30"
                               HeightRequest="30"
                               VerticalOptions="Center" />

                        <Label Text="Add Dream"
                               FontSize="15"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               FontFamily="ProximaNova"
                               TextColor="#98a4b4"/>
                    </StackLayout>


                </StackLayout>

                <!--Financial Management-->

            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         Orientation="Horizontal"
                         Padding="20,10,0,0"
                         Spacing="20">

                    <Image Source="financialmanagementicon.png"
                       WidthRequest="30"
                       HeightRequest="30"
                       VerticalOptions="Center" />

                    <Label Text="Financial Management"
                       FontSize="18"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       FontFamily="ProximaNova"
                       TextColor="#637188"/>


                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             Orientation="Horizontal"
                             Padding="30,5,0,10"
                             Spacing="20">

                        <Image Source="addicon.png"
                           WidthRequest="30"
                           HeightRequest="30"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" />

                        <Label Text="Add Income"
                           FontSize="15"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           FontFamily="ProximaNova"
                           TextColor="#98a4b4"/>
                </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 Padding="30,5,0,10"
                                 Spacing="20">

                        <Image Source="addicon.png"
                               WidthRequest="30"
                               HeightRequest="30"
                               VerticalOptions="Center" />

                        <Label Text="Add Expense"
                               FontSize="15"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               FontFamily="ProximaNova"
                               TextColor="#98a4b4"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             Orientation="Horizontal"
                             Padding="30,5,0,10"
                             Spacing="20">

                    <Image Source="addicon.png"
                           WidthRequest="30"
                           HeightRequest="30"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" />

                        <Label Text="Add Virtual Account"
                           FontSize="15"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           FontFamily="ProximaNova"
                           TextColor="#98a4b4"/>
                </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 Padding="30,5,0,10"
                                 Spacing="20">

                        <Image Source="linkaccounticon.png"
                               WidthRequest="30"
                               HeightRequest="30"
                               VerticalOptions="Center" />

                        <Label Text="Link Account"
                               FontSize="15"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               FontFamily="ProximaNova"
                               TextColor="#98a4b4"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             Orientation="Horizontal"
                             Padding="30,5,0,10"
                             Spacing="20">

                        <Image Source="budgeticon.png"
                           WidthRequest="29"
                           HeightRequest="30"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" />

                        <Label Text="Budget"
                           FontSize="15"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           FontFamily="ProximaNova"
                           TextColor="#98a4b4"/>
                </StackLayout>

                </StackLayout>

            <!--Settings-->

            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         Orientation="Horizontal"
                         Padding="20,10,0,0"
                         Spacing="20">

                    <Image Source="settingsicon.png"
                       WidthRequest="30"
                       HeightRequest="30"
                       VerticalOptions="Center" />

                    <Label Text="Settings"
                       FontSize="18"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       FontFamily="ProximaNova"
                       TextColor="#637188"/>

            </StackLayout>

            <!--Subcription-->
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         Orientation="Horizontal"
                         Padding="20,10,0,0"
                         Spacing="20">

                    <Image Source="subscriptionicon.png"
                       WidthRequest="30"
                       HeightRequest="30"
                       VerticalOptions="Center" />

                    <Label Text="Subcription"
                       FontSize="18"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       FontFamily="ProximaNova"
                       TextColor="#637188"/>

            </StackLayout>

            <!--Feedback-->
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         Orientation="Horizontal"
                         Padding="20,10,0,0"
                         Spacing="20">

                    <Image Source="feedbackicon.png"
                       WidthRequest="30"
                       HeightRequest="30"
                       VerticalOptions="Center" />

                    <Label Text="Feedback"
                       FontSize="18"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       FontFamily="ProximaNova"
                       TextColor="#637188"/>

            </StackLayout>


            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add parent stack layout like :

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                 Orientation="Horizontal"
                 Padding="20,10,0,0"
                 Spacing="20">

        <Image Source="dashbaordmenuicon.png"
               WidthRequest="40"
               HeightRequest="40"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />

        <Label Text="Dashboards"
               FontSize="18"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               FontFamily="ProximaNova"
               TextColor="#637188"/>

    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                     Orientation="Horizontal"
                     Padding="30,5,0,10"
                     Spacing="20">

            <Image Source="summarymenuicon.png"
                   WidthRequest="40"
                   HeightRequest="40"
                   VerticalOptions="Center" />

            <Label Text="Summary"
                   FontSize="15"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   FontFamily="ProximaNova"
                   TextColor="#98a4b4"/>
        </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                 Orientation="Horizontal"
                 Padding="30,5,0,10"
                 Spacing="20">

        <Image Source="spendinghistoryicon.png"
               WidthRequest="40"
               HeightRequest="40"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />

        <Label Text="pending History"
               FontSize="18"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               FontFamily="ProximaNova"
               TextColor="#98a4b4"/>
    </StackLayout>

</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I added that but still same behaviour

Comment: just copy and replace with your code because you are put wrong place end stacklayout in dashbord section

Comment: You can also use grid layout for this

Comment: I have updated my code.. you can see i added one stacklayout for dashbaord.. result is again same.. I even tried putting all menu items under one stack layout that didn't work also

Comment: Look at  `<!--Dreams-->` above this comment section

Comment: `</StackLayout>` is misplaced